# Setting the explicit screenOrientation on a UIViewController for testing purposes

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller, screen-orientation

I'm writing a test on a `UIViewController`. The test has the purpose of testing a state that is only triggered when the device is in portrait mode. Is there a (relatively) simple way to set the "orientation" to portrait to make sure the required code-calls are made?

Answer (score 1):

There are two private `UIApplication` methods: [`rotateIfNeeded:`](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS7-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIApplication.h#L230) and [`rotateIfNeeded:completion:`](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS7-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIApplication.h#L247) which you can use during testing.

Make sure to wrap invocations with `#ifdef` statement, so they don't go into distribution build.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting stuff, but I'm not able to get it to work in a test environment (which is quite common) for this kind of stuff I guess. I check to see if the `UIApplication` is in landscape and call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] rotateIfNeeded:0];` if so. The orientation still reports landscape...

Comment: @nickfalk: I guess you should pass `UIDeviceOrientation` to this method. 0 is `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`, try `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] rotateIfNeeded:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];`

Comment: Thanks, tried but still no go. Doing this without a lot of overhead seems like a lost cause, thanks for the insight though.